# QtGui: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: pyqt6

I installed `pyqt6` using the command:

```
pip install --upgrade pyqt6
```

It was all excellent, and I was able to show a window with this simple example:

```py
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
import sys
    
# Create a PyQt application
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    
# Create a window
window = QWidget()
    
# Show the window
.show()
    
# Exit the application
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

However, when I installed `pyqt6-tools`, I suddenly started to see an issue with loading `QtGui.`

```bash
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtGui: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I tried to uninstall both and let `pyqt6-tools` install the correct `pyqt6` version—unfortunately, the same error. I couldn't even return to `pyqt6`, only a working example.

I created a virtual environment with the same error.

```bash
(pyqtvenv) PS C:\PyQt6Tutorial> pip list
```

```bash
Package          Version
---------------- ---------
click            7.1.2
pip              22.1.2
PyQt6            6.1.0
pyqt6-plugins    6.1.0.2.2
PyQt6-Qt6        6.3.0
PyQt6-sip        13.3.1
pyqt6-tools      6.1.0.3.2
python-dotenv    0.20.0
qt6-applications 6.1.0.2.2
qt6-tools        6.1.0.1.2
setuptools       58.1.0
```

All help is appreciated. I am running Windows 10 and VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-installing the version of python you have on your machine to the most up-to-date one. After I re-installed python to the most recent version, I tried `pip install PyQt6`. That seemed to work for me.

---

I don't know if its relevant for you, but I had to go into window's environmental variables and remove the old python39 and add to the path python310. I'm not sure why the uninstallation processed didn't take care of this automatically.